# Bilingual Q&As?

Tags: discussion

This page should be all English, I know. But if a Q&A is specifically about a language-specific thing (like a [keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/q/1185309/681763)), can this Q&A be offered in two languages, English and the language it affects? This way it would reach more people in the group of those that it affects.

Comment: In this example it would be helpful to write both question and answer such that they apply to any (well, many) keyboard layout(s). Surely it's not only a quirk when using a German keyboard?

Comment: If users *really* can't understand questions and answers written in English then they are unlikely to be coming to an English speaking site like [su] in the first place ...

Comment: @Daniel Beck The Q&A was about what key is what on another keyboard layout and I figured it out by trying everything. Trying the same with every keyboard layout in the world world be pretty much impossible.

Comment: @DavidPostill: But, if a question and answer are posted in both English and some other language (such as German), a user who types a German question into Google might be directed to that page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's tricky.

I think the minimum requirement is it should be *understandable* in english.

And while we have *some* degree of multilingualness in our pool of moderators and users, having content in other languages is going to be a *moderation issue* if we have someone trying to be a smart troll.

If somehow having bits in german or russian can be *integral* to an english language question and it doesn't work otherwise.

As is though, its going to be a lot of trouble for us to manage if its a common thing.

I mean, if TPTB or a broad part of the community said so, and we can somehow work out the moderation issues, especially with non latin scripts, *maybe*. As is, I don't see it as sustainable, and I would be disinclined to acquiescence to this being site policy.